# How to update a AWS::Lambda::Version always to $LATEST in a CF template

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a Cloudformation template with a Lambda@Edge function. This means I need the lambda function, and a Version (type WS::Lambda::Version).

Now, the first time I create the CF template, it works.
But when I update the CF template and the Lambda function is updated, the Lambda version does not get updated (kind of makes sense, it did not change!).

How can I force the Lambda version to update when the Lambda function updates?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script that edits the template before deployment. It can change the version resource name which will create a new version. Finally it will need to make sure the Lambda resource points to that new version name.

You might be able to do it with the new [CloudFormation macros](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html), but I haven't tried that yet so I'm not sure how that would work.

Comment: If change the name, yes you can get a new "version", but obviously that will always be version 1. And the problem with changing the name is that a new function is created. Much slower then updating an existing function.

Comment: Change the name of the version resource, not the function name.